# Find convergence domain of the integral

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

Find convergence domain of $$\int_0^\infty \! \frac{\cos^2{x}}{x^p} \, \mathrm{d}x$$
I've tried to use $\frac{\cos^2{x}}{x^p} < \frac{1}{x^p}$, but $\int_0^\infty \! \frac{1}{x^p} \, \mathrm{d}x$ doesn't converge. So what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That integral never converges. If $p\geq1$, convergence fails $0$. And if $p<1$, convergence fails at $\infty$ (one just removes small intervals around the zeroes of $\cos x$ to see that at $\infty$ the integral behaves like $\int_1^\infty\frac1{x^p}$).

Comment: Thank you! $\frac{\cos^2{x}}{x^p} \sim \frac{1}{x^p}$ at $x \to \infty$ and $x \to 0$, so for all $p$ the integral doesn't converge. Am I right?

Comment: It is a little more subtle than that. The cos touches zero infinitely often, but you can find intervals (all of the same length) where, say, $\cos^2 x \geq 1/2$. Then you show that the integral over those intervals diverges because you bound the integrand below by $\frac1{2x^p}$. This, of course, in the case $p\leq 1$.